# Swift iOS Background Execution Issues

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that downloads JSON file, parses it's contents and sends it to the Watch using WatchConnectivity. Now I want the app to do the same work in the background. I have done some research but still cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone give me a hint? For example: From where to call the data download function and how the function should look like?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background?" Have you started here? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html Note that there is, by design, no way for your application to persistently run when the user is not actively using it. Various use cases are covered in the linked document, however, that do not require that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background fetch` feature of iOS.
for that you can get help from RayWenderlich [Article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/92428/background-modes-ios-swift-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Background Download of the NSURLSession. [Please have a look at this](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-2-background-download-863426842e21#.pws5x5rln).